# Reverting a CSS styled form element back to default browser style

Tags: html, css, firefox, forms, browser

I want to have a default Firefox selectbox, but unfortunately I have a CSS instruction (which I cannot alter or remove) that gives all `select` elements a background and border. Which makes Firefox transform the nice default control to an ugly squared one. Is there a way to remove/revert those instructions?

```
select {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

I've tried to overwrite this definitions with `none`, `auto` and `inherit`, but they didn't have the indended effect.

Answer (score 1):

From forms.css, these are the default styles for Firefox:

```
select {
  margin: 0;
  border-color: ThreeDFace;
  background-color: -moz-Field;
  color: -moz-FieldText;
  font: -moz-list;
  line-height: normal !important;
  white-space: nowrap !important;
  text-align: start; 
  cursor: default;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -moz-appearance: menulist;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-style: inset;
  text-indent: 0;
  overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;
}
```

You could try re-specifying the relevant styles, however you may need to specify different property values for different browsers.

Comment: tried it. the box now looks more default but still has the squared look. event with all instructions set to !important

Comment: can you provide a demo please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding the !important keyword to your overwriting styles?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select {
    background: none !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Can you post a link to the page or the HTML/CSS (the relevant portion) directly here?